# Concatenate multiple expressions into one UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I need to assign the concatenated combination of a static bit of text, followed by an NSNumber, followed by an NSMutableString to the .text property of a UITextField.  I can write any of the three pieces individually to the UITextField, but how would you combine them all into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this example:

```
NSInteger integer = 100;
float float = 43.57;
NSNumber *number = ....;
NSMutableString *string=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"This is string with"];
[string appendFormat:@" int=%d, and float %f and a NSNumber %@", integer, float, number];
```

Now you can set this string to the `UITextField`.

```
yourTextField.text = string;
```

And read this [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: You have a `nil` string and you are using appendFormat:? Why bother, just use `[NSString stringWithFormat:…]` instead.

Comment: @Abizern: Correct, just to use mutableString and use of `appendFormat` as OP asked, I did that way. Now edited the answer, to look better.